# Is it possible to build a custom list using LWC or Aura with rich text field inline editing?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, richtextarea, inline-editing

I have been searching for days but can't seem to find any clue.
I have tried "lightning-datatable" component but it does not work.
I was able to do it in Visualforce but now I need to do it in Lightning.
Any idea where to start?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand what needs to be added there. Doesn't everyone know what a custom list view with Rich Text fields are?